# Azure Calling and skype class duplication

Tags: android, azure, azure-communication-services

```
Duplicate class com.skype.rt.Auf found in modules azure-communication-calling-1.2.0-beta.2-runtime (com.azure.android:azure-communication-calling:1.2.0-beta.2) and trouter-client-android-0.0.1-beta.3-runtime (com.microsoft:trouter-client-android:0.0.1-beta.3)
```

I am getting below build error while using Azure calling and chat library in single application.

```
implementation 'com.azure.android:azure-communication-calling:1.2.0-beta.2'
implementation 'com.azure.android:azure-communication-common:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.azure.android:azure-communication-chat:1.0.0'
```

Comment: You should exclude your module. Also i am hoping that you'r working with AndroidX

Comment: I am excluding the module like below. But then I am getting runtime exception to fetch the real time messages.   implementation ('com.azure.android:azure-communication-chat:1.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.microsoft', module: 'trouter-client-android'
    }

Comment: Should not this _com.skype.rt.Auf_ for exclude?? Also you need to show runtime exception. What is it??

Comment: Have you done with it?

Comment: Yes, I have tried with this. This is the known issues of Azure library so for now I have just put it on hold.

Comment: okay. No issue..

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for asking question! Sorry, currently as the notice mentioned, When using Android Chat and Calling SDK together in the same application, Chat SDK's real-time notifications feature does not work.

The product group is aware of this and exploring supporting such a feature, but as of now not aware of publicly shareable date.
Thanks again for raising this issue.

Further would like to understand your scenario to help to you better on this.
If your requirement meet you can look for Event Grid.
Check this link: [Azure Communication Services as an Event Grid source - Azure Event Grid | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-communication-services)

Please note: Comparing to chat real-time notification, Event Grid does not support "TypingIndicator" and "ReadReceipt".